# this.setState doesn't work in react.js class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use this.setState function in link state I get an empty string from React but actually, that should return a URL. I didn't get how to figure it out, because I used the same method in all of my projects but this doesn't work!!!

```
export class LiveStream extends Component<Props, State> {
  myLink: string;
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      id: "",
      publicKey: "",
      link: "",
      live: true,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const last3 = window.location.href.slice(-42); // ️ Public Key
    console.log(last3);

    let streamKey: any[] = [];

    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(
      "<Contract-Key>",
      LiveStreamContract.abi,
      provider
    );

    const contractData = await contract.getLiveStream();

    for (let index = 0; index < contractData.length; index++) {
      const element = contractData[index];

      if (element.publicKey.toLowerCase() === last3.toLowerCase()) {
        streamKey.push(element);
      }
    }

    const url: string = `http://localhost:8000/live/${streamKey[0].id}.flv`;
    this.setState({ link: url });
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.live === true) {
      return (
        <ReactFlvPlayer
          url={this.state.link}
          isMuted={false}
          isLive={true}
          showControls={false}
          enableStashBuffer={false}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return "offline";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you check that `this.setState` does not work? Your code seems good

Comment: React class components will be deprecated soon in favor of modern functional components with hooks in the near future. Even the new Reactjs beta documentation at https://beta.reactjs.org emphasizes the latter. Most tutorials now teach modern React with no class components so it's better to adopt that approach in order to find help and allow more people to do so for you when you get stuck.

Comment: Maybe try `this.setState({ ...this.state, link: url })` instead so that you don't lose the other key-value pairs.